# How to insert rows with structure from one table to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the query in SQL Server to insert rows with structure from one table to another table?

Comment: Please provide additional details.

Answer (score 4):

A couple ways

**SELECT INTO**

```
SELECT 
   field1,
   field2,
   ...
INTO Table1
FROM Table2
```

**INSERT INTO**

```
INSERT INTO Table1
   field1,
   field2,
   ...
SELECT
   field1,
   field2,
   ...
FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DestTable (Column1,COlumn2)
   SELECT Column1, Column2
   FROM SourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the [INSERT...EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381.aspx#OtherTables) statement that will allow you to do what you need.