# how to insert a table with structure and data into another database?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert rows with structure from one table to another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834835/how-to-insert-rows-with-structure-from-one-table-to-another-table)

how to insert whole table with structure and data into another database?

Comment: IS this a one-time thing or do you need to run it repeatedly and do you need to kepp the data mainatained over time and are you using SQL Server? (inwhich case you need to add the SQL-Server tag)

Answer (score 0):

What database are you working with?

MS SQL has some good data migration tools in the management studio.  There's a wizard to select objects and data and it creates a SQL script to create everything and add the data.